# Changing markup on woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need some help with WooCommerce markup.
I have searched 2 hours on google about this but so far unlucky.

I am trying to find `<strong itemprop="author">asterix</strong>` on WooCommerce templates but I don't see it anywhere.
I am using WooCommerce 2.6.3.

Can anyone let me know where to find it please?

After google suggestion I want to change it from:

```
<strong itemprop="author">asterix</strong>
```

to:

```
<strong itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">asterix</span></strong>
```

Comment: Someone please.

Answer (score 0):

Download Woocommerce on your hard disk, then download notepad++, open it and press ctrl+shift+f and a files search window will appear.

Write `<strong itemprop="author">asterix</strong>` in the search box and specify the search folder as Woocommerce folder

The results will tell you where the markup you are searching for is located

Looks like it is located in

```
woocommerce\templates\single-product\review-meta.php
```

as `<strong itemprop="author"><?php comment_author(); ?></strong>`

There is no `<strong itemprop="author">asterix</strong>` in Woocommerce files so I am guessing that asterix is an author on your domain